# Deprecated function while migrate Joomla 1.0 - Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

I installed Joomla_1.0.15-Stable-Full_Package on localhost, I have installed PHP 5.x & updated mysql. After a struggling installation when I go to my site link thousands of errors appears for Deprecated functions and variables etc..

How could I resolved these ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla is old, thus will work better on old server running PHP 4 and MySQL 4. Joomla 1.0 is too old to work on PHP 5 server due to the fact that so many functions will be depreciated.

Not sure what local server you are using but would recomment using [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and downloading the PHP and SQL addons. If you do doowload PHP4 then you will also need to download Apache 2.0.x. Installing these old packages is very easy, it's just an .exe file therefore like installing a normal bit of software.

[This page shows you the requirements](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/1938/310/) for Joomla 1.0 so you can download the correct packages

Answer (score 1):

The joomla version you're using is too old (from 2008), and some functions used in that time became deprecated thus you get those errors. Sincerely why would you install 1.0 ? It's old, and the risk of being hacked is high. You should at least install 1.5 or even 2.5. If you want to continue using 1.0 (what i really discourage) then maybe you should use an older version of PHP. Which means you've even a higher chance of getting hacked.

Comment: he is installing Joomla 1.0.15 so test migrating as his friend wants to migrate his website which is still running Joomla 1.0

Answer (score -1):

Joomla 1.0 is quite old and probably throws a lot of E_STRICT and E_DEPRECATED warnings by now. I recommend to just turn off error reporting while working with Joomla 1.0. Of course after you done with migrating you should turn it on again on your test environment.

Comment: Why will turning off error reporting help? This will mean he will be running tasks, they won't work and he won't know why

Comment: Since he is just migrating from Joomla 1.0 he shouldn't really be concerned about any errors occurring, he just needs to get the content from it. Of course the dev environment of his target version should have error reporting on.